# Duplicate editor names and no page numbers for book chapters in BibLatex APA using Overleaf

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, overleaf

I am using the apa style with Biblatex on Overleaf, and when I cite a chapter in an edited volume I get two mentions of the editors.

In the APA style there should be only the second of those two mention.

Also, the page number does not appear as should be the case.

Could someone help me solve this?

Two examples below with a screen cap and the bib entries

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{example}
\author{cameron}
\date{May 2020}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Morin220520.bib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\cite{goldberg_constructionist_2013}
\cite{nagle_double_2003}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
@incollection{goldberg_constructionist_2013,
    address = {Oxford},
    title = {Constructionist approaches},
    booktitle = {The {Oxford} {Handbook} of {Construction} {Grammar}},
    publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    author = {Goldberg, Adele},
    editor = {Hoffmann, Thomas and Trousdale, Graeme},
    year = {2013},
    pages = {15--31}
}

@incollection{nagle_double_2003,
    address = {Berlin, Boston},
    title = {Double modals in the {Southern} {United} {States}: syntactic structure or syntactic structures?},
    booktitle = {Modality in {Contemporary} {English}},
    publisher = {Mouton de Gruyter},
    author = {Nagle, Stephen},
    editor = {Facchinetti, Roberta and Palmer, Frank and Krug, Manfred},
    year = {2003},
    pages = {359--72}
}
```

Comment: I am unable to replicate the issue you're experiencing on a system that MacOS 10.15.4 "Catalina", MacTeX2020, biblatex v. 3.14, biber v. 2.14, and APA v. 9.12. Which version does Overleaf employ?

Comment: Just had a look for this information but couldn't find it :(

Comment: The information should  be in the .log and .blg files.

Comment: The raw files page is quite long but here is the first line: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019). Is this the type of version you were asking for?

Comment: This was a bug in earlier versions of `biblatex-apa` (https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/86, related and fixed a little later https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/106, https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/110). With an up-to-date version of `biblatex-apa` the output is as expected. Unfortunately, Overleaf's `biblatex-apa` version still has the bug. Maybe if you bug their customer support enough they will consider updating `biblatex-apa`?

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll use apacite for now then, and wait for the bug fix on Overleaf!

Comment: Note that `apacite` will give you 6th edition APA style. `biblatex-apa` implements 7th edition APA style. If it's 6th edition APA style you are after, you could try `biblatex-apa6` (`style=apa6,`), which did not have this bug (so even though Overleaf is using an older version you may be fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in earlier versions of `biblatex-apa` (https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/86, related and fixed a little later https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/106, https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/110). With an up-to-date version of `biblatex-apa` the output is as expected.

[image: Goldberg, A. (2013). Constructionist approaches. In T. Hoffmann & G. Trousdale (Eds.), The Oxford Handbook of Construction Grammar (pp. 15–31). Oxford University Press.//Nagle, S. (2003). Double modals in the Southern United States: Syntactic structure or syntactic structures? In R. Facchinetti, F. Palmer, & M. Krug (Eds.), Modality in Contemporary English (pp. 359–72). Mouton de Gruyter.]

The current version is `biblatex-apa` v9.12 (2020-05-05) and that is the minimal version you'll want to get.

Unfortunately, Overleaf's now outdated `biblatex-apa`  version still has the bug. Maybe if you bug their customer support enough they will consider updating `biblatex-apa`?

With `biblatex-apa` 9.12 it should in theory be possibly to upload the `.bbx`, `.cbx`, `.dbx` and `.lbx` files to your Overleaf project and use those. This may not be possible in the future if `biblatex-apa` requires a more modern version of `biblatex` and Biber than is available on Overleaf. (This is shown in the second part of my answer to [Citing with biblatex-apa does not output APA7th format?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/550009/35864.))

Comment: I have just sent a query to Overleaf and will "bug" them again if they don't answer in the next few weeks :)

Comment: @Cameron From what I have heard they usually respond very swiftly. But they may tell you that it is not possible to update individual packages outside of their big TeX live updates.