# Bibliography Editor twice (Overleaf)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, apa-style, editors

I switched from \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} to biblatex apa style. 
It worked, but now I have the problem, that the editors show up twice in my bibliography. How can I get rid of the editors in the brackets?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[backend = biber, style = apa, sortcites = true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\title{test}
\author{moritz }
\date{June 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\citeauthor[S.10]{Bauhaus.2016}
\parencite{Bucher.2019}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My bib file looks like this

```
@incollection{Bucher.2019,
 author = {Bucher, Hans-J{\"u}rgen and Barth, Christof},
 title = {Zwischen Hatespeech und Deliberation: Affektive {\"O}ffentlichkeiten und politische Kommunikation in den sozialen Medien},
 pages = {57--81},
 publisher = {{Peter Lang CH}},
 isbn = {9783034336710},
 editor = {Hauser, Stefan and Luginb{\"u}hl, Martin and Tienken, Susanne},
 booktitle = {Mediale Emotionskulturen},
 year = {2019}

@incollection{Bauhaus.2016,
 author = {Bauhaus, Wencke},
 title = {Die Nutzung von Twitter als Erhebungsinstrument f{\"u}r die qualitative empirische Sozialforschung},
 pages = {159--172},
 volume = {36},
 publisher = {{Springer VS}},
 isbn = {978-3-658-11816-7},
 editor = {Schiek, Daniela and Ullrich, Carsten G.},
 booktitle = {Qualitative Online-Erhebungen},
 year = {2016},
 address = {Wiesbaden},
 doi = {10.1007/978-3-658-11817-4_7}
}
```

Blg File

```
[0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.13
[1] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'output.blg'
[66] biber:315> INFO - === Wed Jun  3, 2020, 11:55:20
[116] Biber.pm:375> INFO - Reading 'output.bcf'
[335] Biber.pm:905> INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0
[379] Biber.pm:4196> INFO - Processing section 0
[386] Utils.pm:75> INFO - Globbing data source 'test.bib'
[386] Utils.pm:91> INFO - Globbed data source 'test.bib' to test.bib
[408] Biber.pm:4373> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'test.bib' for section 0
[410] bibtex.pm:1462> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[429] bibtex.pm:1281> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'test.bib'
[564] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[564] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[564] Biber.pm:4024> INFO - Sorting list 'apa/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'apa' and locale 'de-DE'
[565] Biber.pm:4030> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de-DE'
[575] bbl.pm:648> INFO - Writing 'output.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[580] bbl.pm:751> INFO - Output to output.bbl
```

Log File

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.12.13)  3 JUN 2020 12:50
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(/compile/main.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
Package: csquotes 2019-11-15 v5.2h context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count88
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
\csq@reset=\count89
\csq@gtype=\count90
\csq@glevel=\count91
\csq@qlevel=\count92
\csq@maxlvl=\count93
\csq@tshold=\count94
\csq@ltx@everypar=\toks17
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def
File: csquotes.def 2019-11-15 v5.2h csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
)
Package csquotes Info: Trying to load configuration file 'csquotes.cfg'...
Package csquotes Info: ... configuration file loaded successfully.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg
File: csquotes.cfg 
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2019/11/14 3.36 The Babel package
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2019/11/14 3.36 Babel switching mechanism
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngerman.ldf
Language: ngerman 2018/12/08 v2.11 German support for babel (post-1996 orthogra
phy)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngermanb.ldf
Language: ngermanb 2018/12/08 v2.11 German support for babel (post-1996 orthogr
aphy)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2019/11/14 3.36 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count95
\U@D=\dimen103
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count96
)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 121.
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2019/08/31 v3.13a programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2019/11/24 v0.31 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count97
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count98
\c@listtotal=\count99
\c@listcount=\count100
\c@liststart=\count101
\c@liststop=\count102
\c@citecount=\count103
\c@citetotal=\count104
\c@multicitecount=\count105
\c@multicitetotal=\count106
\c@instcount=\count107
\c@maxnames=\count108
\c@minnames=\count109
\c@maxitems=\count110
\c@minitems=\count111
\c@citecounter=\count112
\c@maxcitecounter=\count113
\c@savedcitecounter=\count114
\c@uniquelist=\count115
\c@uniquename=\count116
\c@refsection=\count117
\c@refsegment=\count118
\c@maxextratitle=\count119
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count120
\c@maxextraname=\count121
\c@maxextradate=\count122
\c@maxextraalpha=\count123
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count124
\c@highnamepenalty=\count125
\c@lownamepenalty=\count126
\c@maxparens=\count127
\c@parenlevel=\count128
\blx@tempcnta=\count129
\blx@tempcntb=\count130
\blx@tempcntc=\count131
\blx@maxsection=\count132
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count133
\blx@notetype=\count134
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count135
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count136
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count137
\blx@entrysetcounter=\count138
\labelnumberwidth=\skip43
\labelalphawidth=\skip44
\biblabelsep=\skip45
\bibitemsep=\skip46
\bibnamesep=\skip47
\bibinitsep=\skip48
\bibparsep=\skip49
\bibhang=\skip50
\blx@bcfin=\read1
\blx@bcfout=\write3
\blx@langwohyphens=\language85
\c@mincomprange=\count139
\c@maxcomprange=\count140
\c@mincompwidth=\count141
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def
File: blx-dm.def 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'apa.dbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/apa.dbx
File: apa.dbx 2019/11/29 v9.2 APA biblatex style data model
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count142
\c@savedafterword=\count143
\c@annotator=\count144
\c@savedannotator=\count145
\c@author=\count146
\c@savedauthor=\count147
\c@bookauthor=\count148
\c@savedbookauthor=\count149
\c@commentator=\count150
\c@savedcommentator=\count151
\c@editor=\count152
\c@savededitor=\count153
\c@editora=\count154
\c@savededitora=\count155
\c@editorb=\count156
\c@savededitorb=\count157
\c@editorc=\count158
\c@savededitorc=\count159
\c@foreword=\count160
\c@savedforeword=\count161
\c@holder=\count162
\c@savedholder=\count163
\c@introduction=\count164
\c@savedintroduction=\count165
\c@namea=\count166
\c@savednamea=\count167
\c@nameb=\count168
\c@savednameb=\count169
\c@namec=\count170
\c@savednamec=\count171
\c@translator=\count172
\c@savedtranslator=\count173
\c@shortauthor=\count174
\c@savedshortauthor=\count175
\c@shorteditor=\count176
\c@savedshorteditor=\count177
\c@groupauthor=\count178
\c@savedgroupauthor=\count179
\c@narrator=\count180
\c@savednarrator=\count181
\c@execproducer=\count182
\c@savedexecproducer=\count183
\c@execdirector=\count184
\c@savedexecdirector=\count185
\c@with=\count186
\c@savedwith=\count187
\c@labelname=\count188
\c@savedlabelname=\count189
\c@institution=\count190
\c@savedinstitution=\count191
\c@lista=\count192
\c@savedlista=\count193
\c@listb=\count194
\c@savedlistb=\count195
\c@listc=\count196
\c@savedlistc=\count197
\c@listd=\count198
\c@savedlistd=\count199
\c@liste=\count266
\c@savedliste=\count267
\c@listf=\count268
\c@savedlistf=\count269
\c@location=\count270
\c@savedlocation=\count271
\c@organization=\count272
\c@savedorganization=\count273
\c@origlocation=\count274
\c@savedoriglocation=\count275
\c@origpublisher=\count276
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count277
\c@publisher=\count278
\c@savedpublisher=\count279
\c@language=\count280
\c@savedlanguage=\count281
\c@origlanguage=\count282
\c@savedoriglanguage=\count283
\c@citation=\count284
\c@savedcitation=\count285
\c@pageref=\count286
\c@savedpageref=\count287
\shorthandwidth=\skip51
\shortjournalwidth=\skip52
\shortserieswidth=\skip53
\shorttitlewidth=\skip54
\shortauthorwidth=\skip55
\shorteditorwidth=\skip56
\locallabelnumberwidth=\skip57
\locallabelalphawidth=\skip58
\localshorthandwidth=\skip59
\localshortjournalwidth=\skip60
\localshortserieswidth=\skip61
\localshorttitlewidth=\skip62
\localshortauthorwidth=\skip63
\localshorteditorwidth=\skip64
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
\c@textcitecount=\count288
\c@textcitetotal=\count289
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count290
\c@biburlbigbreakpenalty=\count291
\c@biburlbreakpenalty=\count292
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count293
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count294
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count295
\biburlbigskip=\muskip11
\biburlnumskip=\muskip12
\biburlucskip=\muskip13
\biburllcskip=\muskip14
\c@smartand=\count296
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'apa'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'apa.bbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/apa.bbx
File: apa.bbx 2019/11/29 v9.2 APA biblatex references style
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count297
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count298
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'apa'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'apa.cbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/apa.cbx
File: apa.cbx 2019/11/29 v9.2 APA biblatex citation style
Package biblatex Info: Delimiter 'nameyeardelim' in context '' already defined,
 overwriting.
Package biblatex Info: Delimiter 'nameyeardelim' in context 'textcite' already 
defined, overwriting.
Package biblatex Info: Delimiter 'andothersdelim' in context '' already defined
, overwriting.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\fullcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\citeyear'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetexts'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\citeauthor'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
))
Package csquotes Info: Checking for multilingual support...
Package csquotes Info: ... found 'babel' package.
Package csquotes Info: Adjusting default style.
Package csquotes Info: Redefining alias 'default' -> 'ngerman'.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'ngerman' -> 'ngerman-apa'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'ngerman-apa.lbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/ngerman-apa.lbx
File: ngerman-apa.lbx 2019/11/29 v9.2 APA biblatex localisation
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'ngerman'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'ngerman.lbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/ngerman.lbx
File: ngerman.lbx 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex localization (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'german' -> 'german-apa'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'german-apa.lbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/german-apa.lbx
File: german-apa.lbx 2019/11/29 v9.2 APA biblatex localisation
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'german'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'german.lbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/german.lbx
File: german.lbx 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'ngerman'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'ngerman.lbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/ngerman.lbx
File: ngerman.lbx 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex localization (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'german' -> 'german-apa'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'german-apa.lbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/german-apa.lbx
File: german-apa.lbx 2019/11/29 v9.2 APA biblatex localisation
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'german'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'german.lbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/german.lbx
File: german.lbx 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)))) (/compile/output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
\openout3 = `output.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'output.bbl' found.
(/compile/output.bbl)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 14.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 21.

Overfull \hbox (16.8427pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 22--22
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Hrsg.). In D. Schiek & C. G. Ull-rich (Hrsg.), \OT1/cmr/m/it/10
 Qua-li-ta-ti-ve Online-Erhebungen\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 .
 []

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (/compi
le/output.aux)
Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'output.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `output.run.xml'.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 9346 strings out of 492164
 173035 string characters out of 6125314
 715037 words of memory out of 5000000
 13649 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 7626 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1143 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 58i,6n,63p,820b,5897s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb
></usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></u
sr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb></usr
/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on /compile/output.pdf (1 page, 61985 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 28 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 19 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Thank you!
[image: Editors show up twice]

Comment: In the text you say you are using `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} `, in the code you show biblatex. And the bib entry doesn't fit to your screenshot.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i have been using natbibapa. Now i want to use the code in the box instead, because I have heard, that you should use bibtex instead of natbibapa

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The bib entry is the second entry on the screenshot

Comment: You mean `biblatex`, right?

Comment: If you have a problem with `Bauhaus.2016` then you should post that entry as well. Right now, you are only providing `Bucher.2019`....

Comment: Both have the same Problem. The editor shows up twice. I can provide the entry fpr Bauhaus too!

Comment: I don't get your output. Is your tex system up to date?

Comment: @roarhide - In that case: I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I use overleaf

Comment: @DG' I added the other entry aswell. And yes, i mean biblatex.!

Comment: show the log-file and the blg-file of your example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have. Does it help?

Comment: See https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/110 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/106

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much. It works fine now!

Comment: On a reasonably modern system the `\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}` is no longer needed because `biblatex-apa` already sets it implicitly. You also don't need to write `S.` for page references in citations: `\citeauthor[10]{Bauhaus.2016}` is enough. In the example file `Bucher.2019` is missing its closing curly brace `}`. With that fixed a current version of `biblatex-apa` produces the correct output.

Comment: Given all that, this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/546484/35864

Comment: @moewe Thank you for those information!