# Citing with biblatex-apa does not output APA7th format?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, apa6, apa7

I need to apply the 7th edition of the APA citing guidelines for my thesis. So, recently I switched from `natbib-apa` to `biblatex-apa` according to the answers for this question [Is there a way to apply Apa 7th references and citation style in latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527497/is-there-a-way-to-apply-apa-7th-references-and-citation-style-in-latex) and the references therein. However, my bibliography is still in APA6th format.

I use these packages:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}                               
\usepackage{bookmark}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=black,
            filecolor=black, linkcolor=black,
            urlcolor=blue, linkbordercolor=1 0 0}

% For APA7th edition
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, natbib=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

with the main document as

```
\begin{document}

This is a test where I cite the work of \citep{wilmott_paul_2007}.

\cleardoublepage
\printbibliography
\urlstyle{same}

\end{document}
```

And this is the output then:

[image: Output bibliography]

I linked my `references.bib` file directly with Zotero, so I can't make any changes manually within the `.bib` file. This works actually fine, I don't have any error messages. But the output is not in APA7th format (for books: the location of the publisher is not required any more and should be omitted if I apply `biblatex-apa`).

My first guess was that maybe `hyperref` causes issues, since I first had issues with compiling when switching to `biblatex-apa`. Figured out that I need first to load the package `hyperref` before loading `bookmark`, i.e., without loading `bookmark` I wasn't able to compile in the first place. I am working on Overleaf btw. What am I missing here?

Comment: Check your version of `biblatex-apa`. Only versions from v9.0 (2019-11-23) onwards will give you 7th edition APA style (you'll definitely want the current v9.13 [2020-05-30], though, some earlier versions had small bugs). Older versions of `biblatex-apa` will produce 6th edition APA style. You can easily find out your version of `biblatex-apa` by adding `\listfiles` to the top of your `.tex` file. LaTeX will then write the package/file versions to the end of the `.log` file.

Comment: Ah, I only just saw you are are using Overleaf. Make sure to switch your TeX Live version to 2019 in the menu (see https://de.overleaf.com/blog/new-feature-select-your-tex-live-compiler-version). This will *not* give you the current version 9.13 of `biblatex-apa`, which has all the bugfixes, but will at least give you something that in principle produces 7th edition APA style (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/546484/35864).

Comment: Completely unrelated to the actual issue, but still: With a current version of `biblatex-apa` you won't need the `\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}` any more.

Comment: @moewe thank you for your quick reply! According to the .log file, Overleaf uses ```2019/11/29 v9.2 APA biblatex references style```. I switched also to the TeX Live version 2019, thanks for this hint! Checking out your answer to the linked question means I will have to wait until Overleaf updates the ```biblatex``` package I guess? ... I think there is no other way if I want to stay on Overleaf? Just saw your answer, I will try this out then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only `biblatex-apa` versions from v9.0 (2019-11-23) onwards will give you 7th edition APA style. Older versions still produce 6th edition APA style.

If you want to easily find out your version of `biblatex-apa`, put `\listfiles` at the top of your `.tex` file loading `biblatex-apa` and compile it. LaTeX will list all package versions in a neat little table at the end of the `.log` file. For example on my machine

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
inputenc.sty    2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
   babel.sty    2020/06/10 3.45 The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of b
abel
 british.ldf    2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
csquotes.sty    2019-12-06 v5.2j context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
etoolbox.sty    2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
csquotes.def    2019-12-06 v5.2j csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
csquotes.cfg    
biblatex.sty    2019/12/01 v3.14 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-04 v0.32 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
 ltxcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
     apa.dbx    2020/05/30 v9.13 APA biblatex style data model
blx-compat.def    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
biblatex.def    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
standard.bbx    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
     apa.bbx    2020/05/30 v9.13 APA biblatex references style
     apa.cbx    2020/05/30 v9.13 APA biblatex citation style
biblatex.cfg    
l3backend-pdfmode.def    2020-06-03 L3 backend support: PDF mode
 british.lbx    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
 english.lbx    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
american.lbx    2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
american-apa.lbx    2020/05/30 v9.13 APA biblatex localisation
english-apa.lbx    2020/05/30 v9.13 APA biblatex localisation
british-apa.lbx    2020/05/30 v9.13 APA biblatex localisation
mytest.bbl
  t1cmtt.fd    2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
 ***********
```

which shows that my machine is running `biblatex-apa` v9.13 (2020-05-30).

If you need 7th edition APA style, ensure that your system is fully up to date and that `biblatex-apa` is at least at version v9.12. Previous versions of `biblatex-apa` had bugs (in particular for `@incollection` and `@inproceedings` entries).

---

#### Overleaf only

The most recent version of `biblatex-apa` you can get on Overleaf is v9.2 (2019/11/29). In order to get that version, you need to switch your project TeX Live version to 2019. There are some images about how to do that at the Overleaf blog https://www.overleaf.com/blog/new-feature-select-your-tex-live-compiler-version.

Older TeX live versions than 2019 will not provide `biblatex-apa` versions that produce 7th edition APA style.

But as mentioned above v9.2 still contains some errors. At the moment the only way to get a bug-free `biblatex-apa` version **on Overleaf** is to

1. download `biblatex-apa` from CTAN (https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa, specifically http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa.zip)
2. unzip it, and
3. upload all files with the extension `.bbx`, `.cbx`, `.dbx` and `.lbx` into the root directory of your Overleaf project (the files should be on the same level/in the same folder as your main `.tex` file).
4. Finally, make sure you have TeX Live 2019 selected in your project settings. To avoid trouble with leftover temporary files, clear the cache (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache).

The project would then look roughly like this https://www.overleaf.com/read/wpmfncnzzfkd.

Note that this procedure works at the time of writing this answer, but is not guaranteed to work in the future, since future versions of `biblatex-apa` may require future versions of `biblatex` or Biber that may not be available on Overleaf.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! Uploading the files and importing into the root directory did not help in my case. I'll just stick to the APA6th format then. Thank you again!

Comment: @tanasrad Can you be a bit more specific than "did not help"? Do you get errors or warnings? Did you make sure to upload the files into the root directory of your project? Did you make sure your TeX Live is set to 2019.

Comment: So, I uploaded the ```.bbx```, the ```.cbx``` and the ```.lbx``` files into a folder in my project and imported then in the preamble of my ```main.tex``` file (I suppose this is the root directory). I changed the TeX Live version to 2019 and compiled. As a result, I get in the first line of the bibliography the message ```@lasthash``` while the source itself appears, albeit with some ```@``` signs in between the name, year and journal. However, the location is not listed anymore, but stuff like ```@colon@search``` and ```@savepunctstate@restorepunctstate``` mess up the entire source

Comment: I just realised, if I switch TeX Live back to 2017 (Legacy), the source appears correctly within the bibliography, only at the end of the source there is ```(Cit. on p. 1).``` which is not APAstyle I guess? I actually tried out all TeX Live versions, and the 2017 is by far the best, if only the ending with the indication on which page it is cited could be omitted.

Comment: @tanasrad The "root folder" is the folder where your main `.tex` file is located. Ideally the `.bbx`, `.cbx`, `.dbx`, `.lbx` should be at the same level as your main `.tex` file (they should not be in a separate folder). You should then not have to specify anything special in your main `.tex` file/preamble. Just say `style=apa,` (do *not* try to do things with relative paths). If you are fed up with `biblatex-apa` and 7th edition APA style, switch to TeX Live 2019 and take `style=apa6,` instead of `style=apa,`.

Comment: I reallocated all the files to the same level as the main ```.tex``` file. However, I get now error messages at the line of ```\begin{document}``` which says: ```Package biblatex error: option 'sorting=apa' invalid```. And, what do you exactly mean with "just say ```style=apa```? Where should I input that statement? I already have this option for the ```biblatex``` package. Using TeX Live 2019 with APA6th doesn't work aswell, i.e., the bibliography is not correctly according the guidelines for APA. The colon ```:``` between the publisher and location is replaced by a comma instead.

Comment: plus, I get an error message for the files ```apa.bbx``` which says: ```Missing \begin{document}``` and ```undefined control sequence``` at line 246 of ```apa.bbx```.

Comment: @tanasrad By ""just say `style=apa`" I meant that you should only pass the `style=apa` option to `biblatex`. You need not to more in your preamble. In fact your document/preamble should look the same as always. I wasn't sure if you had done anything odd because you mention having imported the files in the preamble. The error `Package biblatex error: option 'sorting=apa' invalid` is puzzling because `apa.bbx` defines that sorting scheme. (This relies on TeX Live 2019. You may want to clear the cache (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache) after switching TeX Live versions.)

Comment: @tanasrad I also did not manage to reproduce the incorrect comma with `style=apa6,`. I get the expected colon on Overleaf and on my local machine.

Comment: guess what buddy?! Thanks for your help, clearing the cache, uploading the files to the same level as the main file and setting TeX Live to 2019 worked just fine! How can I mark your comments as answers which solved my problem? Thanks again moewe!

Comment: @tanasrad I updated the answer to mention more explicitly what I mean by "root directory" and added a note about clearing the cache. If the answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the little green checkmark on the top left (https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234). You cannot accept comments, but the answer should contain all the important bits anyway.

Comment: Great, I checked your answer as the most helpful! Thanks again moewe!